# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) whenever using apt-get

Tags: linux, ubuntu, generics, kernel

I have searched all over the internet, and have found that many people have nearly the exact same problem, but differ from mine in some small way. I've tried just about every solution I've found and nothing has worked.

Whenever using apt-get, I get a big error, I won't post the entire output because of how big it is but it ends with

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
```

`E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
    update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic with 
    1.
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return 
    code 1
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic (--
    configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
    status 1
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were 
    encountered while processing:
    linux-firmware
    linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic
    linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
    linux-generic-lts-xenial
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic`

`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

I've spent hours trying to find a solution and nothing works, many suggest methods that use `sudo apt-get autoclean` etc, but this doesn't work considering every time I use `apt-get` I get this same error.

The output of `uname -r` is `4.4.0-103-generic`

The files in my /boot directory are

```
abi-4.4.0-103-generic         lost+found
abi-4.4.0-104-generic         memtest86+.bin
config-4.4.0-103-generic      memtest86+.elf
config-4.4.0-104-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin
grub                          System.map-4.4.0-103-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic  System.map-4.4.0-104-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-103-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic   vmlinuz-4.4.0-104-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 0):

If you do a df -h and check for the filesystems, either your / is full or your /boot is full. You can remove old kernels with apt-get autoremove